# Assembly resolve at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, resolver

I want to load assemblies dynamically in my app with the `AssemblyResolver` event, but I don't understand how to do it.

I've saw this [tutorial](http://www.aboutmycode.com/net-framework/assemblyresolve-event-tips/) and tried it myself.
In tip 3 he wrote:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += ResolveAssembly;
}
static void Print()
{
    var mainClass = new MainClass();
    mainClass.Print();
}

static Assembly ResolveAssembly(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    return Assembly.LoadFile(@"path to the library");
}
```

Actually I don't understand how this code should compile at all...
The `new MainClass()` cannot be compiled as it unknown (the type isn't loaded yet), the loading happens at runtime.
If the `MainClass` was known type, it shouldn't be resolved at all...

How this code should work?

Comment: i think the `print` is some method just for debugging(such as, call stack), and not mean something contained in the loaded assembly. the ahthor should have given the code in previous chapters.

Answer (score 1):

If *compiles* because presumably you have *a* reference to the library with a `MainClass` type and `Print` method, even if it is an empty stub without any actual implementation - or just the wrong implementation. It isn't "unknown". If it *was* unknown, then indeed this code wouldn't compile, and you'd have to use reflection to find the type at runtime, and reflection to instantiate the instance, and reflection to invoke the `Print()` method (unless there is some well-known interface or base-class you can cast to, or you use `dynamic`).

That is all you need to compile something: the metadata. In fact, it is *relatively common* to target "reference libraries" that are exactly that - this is precisely how many of the multi-targeting features in your IDE work.

At *runtime*, you can override the load to provide the *intended* library, but to be honest it is usually easier just to deploy the *actual* library into the probe path(s) of your application (typically: next to the main exe). Also, in your `ResolveAssembly` method, it would be a good idea to check *which assembly is being requested* - it could be trying to load something completely unrelated, in which case just leave it alone.

Comment: But if I add empty stub as reference to the project, `ResolveAssembly` will be raised when the `new MainClass()` will appear?

Comment: @nrofis it will happen when the JIT needs it, so *at the latest* when `new MainClass()` runs, but possibly earlier

Comment: Even if `MainClass` is known and exists in the references?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load an assembly of which you don't know the content (and then use reflection to instantiate its classes), you can simply use [`Assembly.Load()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky3942xh(v=vs.110).aspx) if you have its fullname (name, version, culture and public key token if present), or [`Assembly.LoadFrom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28(v=vs.110).aspx) if you have its pathname.

The `AssemblyResolve` is used to "redirect" the loading of an assembly that is "known" at compile-time but that at runtime time must be loaded from a specific path. You can clearly use it to "bait and switch" the assembly (at compile time you have an assembly, at runtime you load a different assembly that implements the same classes).